# How to get the sum of all numbers in nested dictionaries recursively?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I am trying to get the sum of all numbers from a nested dictionary recursively but my code keeps throwing me an error. I'm not sure what other changes I can make to fix this so any help would be appreciated!

```
obj = {
    "a":2,
    "b":{"x":2, "y":{"foo":3, "z":{"bar":2}}},
    "c":{"p":{"h":2, "r":5}, "q":"ball", "r":5},
    "d":1,
    "e":{"nn":{"lil":2},"mm":"car"}}
    
def recursive_sum(n):
    current_sum = 0
    for key in n:
        if not isinstance(n[key], dict):
            current_sum = current_sum + n[key]
        else: 
            current_sum = current_sum + recursive_sum(n[key])
    return current_sum

recursive_sum(obj)
```

The following is the error message I keep getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-04d5913ff6b1> in <module>
     15     return current_sum
     16 
---> 17 recursive_sum(obj)

<ipython-input-18-04d5913ff6b1> in recursive_sum(n)
     12             current_sum = current_sum + n[key]
     13         else:
---> 14             current_sum = current_sum + recursive_sum(n[key])
     15     return current_sum
     16 

<ipython-input-18-04d5913ff6b1> in recursive_sum(n)
     10     for key in n:
     11         if not isinstance(n[key], dict):
---> 12             current_sum = current_sum + n[key]
     13         else:
     14             current_sum = current_sum + recursive_sum(n[key])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: You have `"q":"ball"` and `"mm":"car"`; you might want to handle these

Comment: You say that the code is supposed to sum the even numbers that are found in the nested dictionaries. In your own words, what part of your code is intended to make sure that the things you're summing are even numbers? Or indeed that they are numbers at all? If you didn't even get *that* far in your analysis of the code, I have to be skeptical that it's actually your own code in the first place.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel typo mistake, which I have now corrected. I have to sum the numbers in my code but an important part of it is to differentiate the numbers and the strings, I tried handling this by typecasting but was not successful. Hence, I asked for help here. You should try not being too skeptical of others, my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, there is at least one instance where current_sum is an `integer` and n[key] is a `string`. And Python can do `+` operations on these types.

In your case, the issue comes from `"q":"ball"`

How to find this out?

- Use a python debugger (most of the IDE support this out of the box)
- Try online debugger (Example: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_debugger)
- Try to print n[Key] above  `current_sum = current_sum + n[key]`

Here is the modified version of your code (with a additional condition):

```
obj = {
    "a":2,
    "b":{"x":2, "y":{"foo":3, "z":{"bar":2}}},
    "c":{"p":{"h":2, "r":5}, "q":"ball", "r":5},
    "d":1,
    "e":{"nn":{"lil":2},"mm":"car"}}
    
def recursive_sum(n):
    current_sum = 0
    for key in n:
        
        if not isinstance(n[key], dict) :
            if  not isinstance(n[key], str) :
                current_sum = current_sum + n[key]
        else: 
            current_sum = current_sum + recursive_sum(n[key])
    return current_sum

recursive_sum(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

as Mustafa Aydın said, you getting error because you have strings in values.
If they are not error but part of your input then

```
def recursive_sum(n):
    current_sum = 0
    if(not isinstance(n,str)):
        for i,j in n.items():
            if(isinstance(j,int)):
                current_sum += j
            else:
                current_sum += recursive_sum(j)
    return current_sum
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

you have to handle for non integer values like this:

```
def recursive_sum(n):
    current_sum = 0
    for key in n:
        if not isinstance(n[key], dict) :
            if type(n[key]) is int:
                current_sum = current_sum + n[key]
        else:
            current_sum = current_sum + recursive_sum(n[key])
    return current_sum
```